# SQLiteStudio - CREATE DATABASE - Cannot Execute Query on Undefined or Invalid Database

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I'm new to sql, and i ran the query to create a database

```
CREATE DATABASE test
```

However, SQLiteStudio, outputs the error `Cannot Execute Query on Undefined or Invalid Database`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since SQLite is a file-level and not server-level DBMS, the command `CREATE DATABASE ...` is not supported as there is no server instance to invoke the command.

To create SQLite databases, you would need to create the file beforehand (outside of SQL code) via the CLI executable, `sqlite3`, or application layer code (Python, PHP, etc.).